# Downstream SwiftUI view doesn't seem to pick up the Firebase Auth/users collection values from login

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to store a user profile from a Cloud Firestore Users collection, and have it be instantiated right when logging into the app, and make it editable from a downstream profile view, but I keep running into this " 'self' used before all stored properties are initialized" error.

I have an AuthenticationState class that handles login with Firebase Auth, stores the current logged-in user, and creates a document in my users collection that matches the auth user ID.
It also stores this as a userProfile variable within the authState class.

I think this is probably happening because I'm not storing this in a way that makes sense - I want to have this userProfile be a global variable that can be accessed by any view or View Model, and to make sure that it's instantiated based on the currently logged in Firebase Auth user, no matter where I access it from.

## Current Code

I instantiate the authState class directly from my main app, and set it up as an environmentObject from the main view:

```
@main
struct GoalTogetherApp: App {

    let authState: AuthenticationState
    
    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        self.authState = AuthenticationState.shared
        
        setupFirebase()
    }
 
 
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(authState)
        }
    }
}
```

And the class contains these variables (among others). Both loggedInUser and userProfile (which is the one I'm most interested in), start out as nil, and there are no initializers.
Once the sign in functions are called, that triggers loggedInUser to be set, and loggedInUser being set triggers userProfile to be set to the profile of the matching user in the users collection (or create a new one in Firestore if none exists, and set this variable to that):

```
class AuthenticationState: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    // The firebase logged in user, and the userProfile associated with the users collection
    @Published var loggedInUser: User?
    @Published var userProfile: UserProfile?
    static let shared = AuthenticationState()
```

Then I try to initialize it from the ProfilePage, like so (I'm trying to have email, and then other variables, be editable within the page, and then when they're saved, call back to the Firestore users collection document to update it):

```
struct ProfilePage: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var authState: AuthenticationState
    
    // @State var profile: UserProfile
    
    @State var email: String
    
    init() {
        let profile = authState.userProfile!
        
        if profile.email != nil {
            _email = State(initialValue: profile.email!)
        } else {
            _email = State(initialValue: "")
        }
    }
```

And I get a " 'self' used before all stored properties are initialized' error on the first line of the init (let profile = ...)

I'm assuming this is because it's creating a new instance of authState where userProfile is not already set. Wondering if there are any best practices for how to store this so I'm able to pick up that value that was set when the user logged in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to just give your `email` variable an initial value when declaring it:

```
struct ProfilePage: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var authState: AuthenticationState
    @State var email: String = "" //<-- Here
    
    init() {
        let profile = authState.userProfile!
        
        if profile.email != nil {
            _email = State(initialValue: profile.email!)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Email", text: $email)
    }
}
```

However, I'd suggest that you may find potential issues with this strategy of doing everything in `init`. Because SwiftUI views are transient, if you had something that re-rendered the view hierarchy while a user was editing the field on this page, for example, you might find the `@State` getting reset while editing, for example. To avoid that, you might want to consider setting your values in `onAppear`:

```
struct ProfilePage: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var authState: AuthenticationState
    @State var email: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("Email", text: $email)
        }.onAppear {
            email = authState.userProfile?.email ?? ""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks jnpdx, I tried that - this might be an important thing for me to test your other solution there. These options solved the Xcode error I was getting. I noticed I'm having another downstream issue that is causing my email not to get populated, so I posted that there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67139077/subscribing-to-a-user-variable-from-my-authentication-class-in-an-unrelated-view. But this has fixed my immediate Xcode error, thanks!