# Subscribing to a user variable from my authentication class in an unrelated ViewModel - Swift/Combine

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication, combine

I'm trying to instantiate a user profile based on the logged in user from my AuthenticationState class (using Firebase Auth). This user profile is part of my UserProfileViewModel, which should power a view for editing the user's profile.

But it appears that the loggedInUser is still seen as nil when the UserProfileViewModel is instantiated, and I'm not sure if there's a way I can use a Combine subscription from another class like this to make sure I'm subscribed to the loggedInUser published variable of that specific instance of Authentication state.

Authentication state is called by my main app file, as an environment object - once the user logs in, the loggedInUser is set to that Firebase Auth user:

```
class AuthenticationState: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    // The firebase logged in user, and the userProfile associated with the users collection
    @Published var loggedInUser: User?
    
    
    @Published var isAuthenticating = false
    @Published var error: NSError?
    
    static let shared = AuthenticationState()
    
    private let auth = Auth.auth()
    fileprivate var currentNonce: String?
```

I initialize AuthenticationState in my main app file:

```
@main
struct GoalTogetherApp: App {

    let authState: AuthenticationState
    
    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        self.authState = AuthenticationState.shared
        
        setupFirebase()
    }
 
 
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(authState)
        }
    }
}
```

And I have this other class that I want to grab the loggedInUser, and then use that user's uid to create or find a userProfile from Cloud Firestore:

```
class UserProfileViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var loggedInUser: User?
    @Published var userProfile: UserProfile?
    
    private let auth = Auth.auth()
    private let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    init() {
        self.loggedInUser = AuthenticationState.shared.loggedInUser
        
        if self.loggedInUser != nil {
            self.userProfile = self.loadUser()
        }
    }
```

And the Profile page is supposed to grab that and pull the email from the UserProfile, but it keeps coming up as blank:

```
struct ProfilePage: View {
    @ObservedObject var userProfileVM = UserProfileViewModel()
    
    @State var email: String = ""
    
    init() {
        print("User Profile VM equals: \(String(describing: userProfileVM.userProfile))")
        if userProfileVM.userProfile?.email != nil {
            _email = State(initialValue: userProfileVM.userProfile!.email!)
        } else {
            _email = State(initialValue: "")
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to apply it here, but the solution is almost certainly to use `addStateDidChangeListener` as shown in the first snippet in here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user

Comment: try using `AuthenticationState.shared.$loggedInUser.sink(receiveValue: {...})` to update the `loggedInUser` in `UserProfileViewModel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the instance method `addStateDidChangeListener(_:)` of Firebase's Auth class and assign the `User` instance passed in via the completion handler to your own property of `loggedInUser` in `AuthenticationState`. This way, you'll get notified whenever the user logs in or out - staying in sync. Like so:

```
class AuthenticationState: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var loggedInUser: User?
    
    //...other properties...

    static let shared = AuthenticationState()
    private let auth = Auth.auth()
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        auth.addStateDidChangeListener { [weak self] (_, user) in
            self?.loggedInUser = user
        }
    }
    
}
```

Then, you're correct in that you can use Combine to form a data pipeline between your `AuthenticationState` instance and `UserProfileViewModel` instance. Instead of a one-time assignment during `init()` (as you have currently), you can use Combine's `sink(receiveValue:)` method to bind `UserProfileViewModel`'s `loggedInUser` property to `AuthenticationState`'s:

```
class UserProfileViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var loggedInUser: User?
    init() {
        AuthenticationState.shared.$loggedInUser
            .sink { [weak self] user in
                self?.loggedInUser = user
            }
            .store(in: &subs)
    }
    private var subs: Set<AnyCancellable> = .init()
}
```

Using `$loggedInUser` accesses the built-in publisher provided by `@Published`. And here you can sink and create a subscription. Note, also, the storage of the `AnyCancellable` returned by `sink(receiveValue:)`. Keep a strong reference to this for however long `UserProfileViewModel` needs to be around for.

Comment: thanks for the clear, awesome solution. This worked way better. And it also kept my login from last time when I re-launched the app, so I got that for free with your solution :) Thanks!